# Get range/slice from numpy array the size of another array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tuples, slice

I have two numpy arrays, one bigger than another, but both with the same number of dimensions.

I want to get a slice from the bigger array that matches the size of the smaller array. (Starting from `0,0,0....`)

So, imagine the big array has shape (10,5,7).
And the small array has shape (10,4,6).

I want to get from the bigger array this slice:

```
biggerArray[:10,:4,:6]
```

The length of the shape tuple may vary, and I want to do it for any number of dimensions (Both will always have the same number of dimensions).

How to do that? Is there a way to use tuples as ranges in slices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Construct the tuple of `slice` objects manually. `biggerArray[:10, :4, :6]` is syntactic sugar for `biggerArray[(slice(10), slice(4), slice(6))]`, so:

```
biggerArray[tuple(map(slice, smallerArray.shape))]
```

or

```
biggerArray[tuple(slice(0, n) for n in smallerArray.shape)]
```

You may want to `assert result.shape == smallerArray.shape` afterwards, just in case the input shapes weren't what you thought they were.